# Parse SOAP response and extract specific node using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to interact with a SOAP service.
I'm able to get the SOAP response and by using `Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();` and `transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);` , I'm able to see what the output/response is and displaying it in the console.

But, I need to extract `sessionID` from the response and send that `sessionID` in a different SOAP request.

Please suggest me the extraction method, building a new SOAP request

***Parsing is what I need to do!!***

Below is the code for sending the request to the SOAP service:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "https://WWW.DUMMYURL.COM";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);


        // Process the SOAP Response
        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

        soapConnection.close();
     } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        String serverURN = "urn:DUMMYURL.COM";
        String serverNS0 = "http://WWW.DUMMYURL.COM";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("urn", serverURN);
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns0", serverNS0);

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();     
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBody.addChildElement("login","urn");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem1.addChildElement("username","urn");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("USERNAME");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem4 = soapBodyElem1.addChildElement("password","urn");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem5 = soapBodyElem4.addTextNode("PASSWORD");
        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "https://WWW.DUMMYURL.COM"  + "login");
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        //Print the request message
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return soapMessage;
}


    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {  

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        String source = sourceContent.toString();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");

        // Format it
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        System.out.println(transformer.toString());
}
```

Can someone please suggest me a snippet on **how should I save the response I'm getting to a file locally?**

Currently in the above code the `response` is getting displayed in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `writeTo` method of the `SOAPMessage` interface to do the same, for example:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("somefile");
soapResponse.writeTo(out);
```

Vinod.